# I am not able to the image in list view of sObject

Tags: lightning, list-view

We have an issue that we have not get the image on the salesforce lightning rather than we get a text "undefined" in place of the image in list view on 'Case' object but we getting the image in salesforce classic. How can we get the image in salesforce lightning? And also why this is happening?

Comment: Refine your question and please provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Are you using formula field to display the image?